# Can you think of some way to remove a button from a compiled vb6 application

Tags: api, vb6, reverse-engineering, decompiling

We have a VB6 application running at a customer that has a bug in it when the user clicks on the Help button. A quick and easy fix would be to somehow remove the button so that they cannot click it (recompiling isn't an option btw). Possibly a separate app running that is constantly looking for this form and then somehow removing/hiding the button. Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: It seems it would be a lot easier to ask the user not to click the offending button.

Comment: The problem is that in doing so it is showing them some privileged information about the person they are looking at the properties - not just the Help file. Sounds a strange bug I know and it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to [find](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/activate-window-api) the button window handle using the caption and maybe the class, and then [disable it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This would be **pure unadulterated evil**, and would sooner or later cause immense pain to you or (worse) an innocent colleague. You *really should* recompile the application, unless threatened by something worse than a velociraptor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion led me down the path of using EnumWindows and EnumChildWIndows then using EnableWindow to disable the button and it works. You are correct of course, but you assume that the source code exists (big assumption). This only affects one customer and they will be upgraded in time to the latest version (for which we do have the source) and in which the bug has been fixed!

Comment: I'm glad it helps... keep an eye out for those dinosaurs though!